# Smart quotes are not so smart in the new design, it seems

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Check it out:

[image: more like dumb quotes amirite]

Those leading single quotation marks are backwards. Crazy talk!

Comment: This could be a font issue. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Jin [Font issues are awesome](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/system-message-renders-a-very-favorably)!

Comment: I dislike smart quotes.

Comment: Woo, extra attention for my question!

Comment: @Jack I do too. But if we have to use them they should at least be correct.

Comment: What’s to dislike about smart quotes?

Comment: @ghoppe they'd be fine if they were really smart, but so often the wrong one gets chosen.

Comment: @JackBNimble These aren't “smart quotes”: smart quotes are when an editor automatically converts `"` into `“` or `”`, and `'` into `‘` or `’`. Using “these” or ‘these’ quotes is normal English typography; "these" or 'these' quotes are typewriter-era approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a font issue; you can verify by cutting and pasting [the question title](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/are-droids-a-he-she-or-an-it) into a document with a different font, or even Notepad, etc.

## Are droids a 'he/she' or an 'it'?

`Are droids a 'he/she' or an 'it'?`

Those single quotes `'` aka ' renders in the font chosen for this site as the above image in the question. So by design unless you can convince Jin to change the font (which to be honest, I am not particularly fond of, but not enough that I want to fight about it).

Comment: To demonstrate this, I edited the example question to use proper single quotation marks (i.e. ‘ and not '), and it renders correctly.  So if you use the right character, you see the right characters :)

Answer (score 1):

In the *new* new design, the font has been changed sufficiently that **ordinary single quotes are no longer converted into smart quotes.**

Since the quotes in the originally linked post have been edited to ‘these’ rather than 'these', I've had to choose a different post for a screenshot to demonstrate this:

[image: single]

---

**Ordinary *double* quotes *are* still converted into smart quotes, but in the correct manner:**

[image: double]

Comment: Wow. I've not only answered a [meta-tag:bug] report from a CM, but I've also changed a [meta-tag:status-bydesign] from *Jeff Atwood* to [meta-tag:status-completed]! I feel really grown-up now :-P